# View internal server's website through main web server

Tags: linux, web-server, apache2

So this one is a little hard for me to explain,

I have two servers, hypothetically named Orion, and the other is Behemoth. Orion is my web server and Behemoth is my VM host. Orion's web server is hosted on ports 80 and 443, and Behemoth's control panel is on port 8006. Is it possible to set up a page on Orion to act as a gateway into Behemoth's page (i.e. using iframes in html or something more technical)? I have a couple of VMs that would require similar setup, but I am mostly concerned about Behemoth's panel.

Orion is running Ubuntu with an Apache web server. Behemoth is running Proxmox 4.4

P.S: I am a cyber student who uses VMs at a school that has extremely strict firewall rules that doesn't allow ports other than 80 and 443, so just using my domain name and port forwarding wouldn't quite solve the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not? [They even document this.](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Web_Interface_Via_Nginx_Proxy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. It is called "reverse proxy."

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension

I am assuming you know how a proxy works. If not here is a small summary:
Orion will access Behemoth on your behalf. However, to Behemoth it will look like if Orion is the client. Then Orion will just forward the result to you.

Comment: Thank you, but now comes the error of 'REVERSE' not being a recognized command for Apache, even after enabling all of the modules listed

Comment: Can you post your config?

Comment: I was an idiot, The config was right, the lines of comments that I wrote for the configuration had a single line without a '#'. Thank you